# Sqoop : import all tables converting blob types

Tags: oracle, sqoop

I'm trying to import all the tables from my Oracle 11g R2 (import-all-tables) and I'm facing a problem with a CLOB type. (Using CDH 5.9, Sqoop 1.4.6-cdh5.9.1)

First try :

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect ... --hive-import --hive-overwrite --as-parquet-file --autoreset-to-one-mapper -m XX --direct
```

Tables are correctly imported until one table with a CLOB column is found and throw the following error : Cannot convert to SQL type 2005.

Second try:

```
sqoop import-all-tables -D oraoop.disabled=true --connect ... --hive-import --hive-overwrite --as-parquet-file --autoreset-to-one-mapper -m XX
```

I get the same error.

Third try

```
sqoop import --connect ... --hive-import --hive-overwrite --as-parquet-file --autoreset-to-one-mapper -m XX --table MyClobTable --map-column-java CLOBCOL=String
```

This works, so I try to get the same with all the tables:

```
sqoop import-all-tables --connect ... --hive-import --hive-overwrite --as-parquet-file --autoreset-to-one-mapper -m XX --map-column-java CLOBCOL=String
```

This fails because just one of my tables has got a CLOBCOL column.

Is there a way to use import-all-tables, fixing the 2005 SQL type error, or telling Sqoop how to resolve it "on the fly"?

Thanks!

Comment: what is the problem you're seeing exactly?  Instead of trying to force clobs to strings, you should consider letting sqoop store the files as needed for their size (if relatively small, can be inline, else in _lobs subdir ).

Comment: I edited my post trying to be more explicit. How can I "let Sqoop store the files as needed for their size" ?

Answer (score 0):

you should not use --direct command as the sqoop document says "Sqoop’s direct mode does not support imports of BLOB, CLOB, or LONGVARBINARY columns. Use JDBC-based imports for these columns; do not supply the --direct argument to the import tool."